# Chart.js display date from firestore using Angular error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toDate')

Tags: angular, date, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, chart.js

The user adds date from mat datepicker and stores in firestore (e.g 15 October 2023 of type timestamp) . This is suppose to display in x-axis of chart in the format 15/10/2023. I have used

```
          const dateLabels = this.data.map((item) => item.weightDate).sort();       
          const monthLabels =  dateLabels.map(a=>this.datePipe.transform(a.toDate(), 
                                   'dd/MM/YYYY'));  

 this.chart = new Chart('MyChart', {
        type: 'line',
         data: {
         labels: monthLabels,
         datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Weight',
            data: weightLabels,
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        aspectRatio: 2.5,        
      },
```

**Getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toDate')**

Comment: Would be great if you can provide the response data. The error mentions there is a value (`a`) that is `null`.

Comment: @YongShun sorry do you mean the backend data?

Comment: Yes, the data returned from Firebase.